# search through the command history in the terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, history

Have you ever used a `command` in the Terminal, but then later `forgot what you typed`, and wished there was some way that you could view the last used commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to search through your command history. Here are 3:

1. use the `up and down arrows` on your keyboard when at the command prompt.
2. use the `history` command.
3. Simply press : `Control + R` when at the command prompt.

**E.g** : `Control + R` , then write ***`php`***

[image]

Comment: What about just `history`? EDIT: You're welcome ;)

Comment: If you need to see all of the commands history just type : `history` , but if you forgot a command that you typed before use `Control + R`

Comment: Sure, but omitting `history` would make this answer incomplete. Generally speaking, this question is also off-topic for StackOverflow since it does not directly relate to programming.

Comment: History command is best option for review all previous commands, using of this command all previous commands are showing in one page, so that you can easy check logs of command and you can also use up and down arrow for review the last command

http://studentthadi.com/news/post/history-command-in-linux/11

Answer (score 2):

I often use bash-builtin command "history" to search for a certain command, e.g. to get the last sudo command type:

```
history | grep sudo | tail -n 1
```

gives the last command (with number) with sudo in it. "tail -n 1" gives the last matched line. Then use

```
!<number>
```

to execute exactely this command.

```
!-1
```

executes the last command, by the way. works well in bash.

Comment: to repeat last command, simply use `!!`

Comment: @FredrikPihl good :D , i don't know it before , thnx +1